# puts @visited.inspect not showing anything

Tags: ruby, debugging

I'm trying to understand this code, so i put a
`puts @visited.inspect`
or a
`puts visited.inspect`
but nothing is displayed. The code is running fine and is the following

```
grid = [  ["1","1","1","1","0"],  ["1","1","0","1","0"],  ["1","1","0","0","0"],  ["0","0","0","0","0"]]

def max_area_of_island(grid)
    @visited = Set.new
    @grid = grid

    total_sum = [0] 
    @m = grid.length 
    @n = grid[0].length 

    i = 0
    while i < @m 
        j = 0 
        while j < @n
            if grid[i][j] == 1 && !@visited.include?([i,j])
               @visited << [i,j]
                puts @visited.inspect
               total_sum << bfs([i,j])
            end 
            j += 1
        end 
        i += 1
    end 

    total_sum.max
end
```

i put a
`puts @visited.inspect`
and a
`puts visited.inspect`

The code runs smoothly but It did prints anything. What can I do to print the values of @visited, just to inspect what the program is doing or... DO you sugest I should debug this code.. Where? Or which program?

Answer (score 0):

Your `grid` variable stores strings, but in the following, you are comparing `grid[i][j]` to an integer. This will always be false.

> ```
>           if grid[i][j] == 1 && !@visited.include?([i,j])
> ```

Without the definition of `bfs` I cannot verify if this is the only issue with your code.